# Undefined control sequence on \subtitle

Tags: koma-script

Using the very simple LaTeX document below, named `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\title{(Title)}
\subtitle{(Subtitle)}
\author{(Author)}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

When running `latex test.tex`, I am getting the error reported as follows in the log file:

```
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6)
 %&-line parsing enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>
Babel <v3.8h> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, arabic, basque, bulgarian, coptic, welsh, czech, slovak, german, ng
erman, danish, esperanto, spanish, catalan, galician, estonian, farsi, finnish,
 french, greek, monogreek, ancientgreek, croatian, hungarian, interlingua, ibyc
us, indonesian, icelandic, italian, latin, mongolian, dutch, norsk, polish, por
tuguese, pinyin, romanian, russian, slovenian, uppersorbian, serbian, swedish, 
turkish, ukenglish, ukrainian, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2006/07/30 v2.95b KOMA-Script document class (article)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package scrlfile, 2006/03/28 v2.95 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package typearea, 2006/07/30 v2.95b KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-2002

)) (./test.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \subtitle
             {(Subtitle)}
? 
[1] [2] (./test.aux) )
Output written on test.dvi (2 pages, 484 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Is there something else I need to define or include to make this work?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What should `$ cat test.tex` be? Commenting that line out, it works. But it seems your distribution hasn't been updated in a long time.

Comment: Seems like you are using an outdated LaTeX system, Update your system and your code will work (commenting out the `$ cat test.tex` line)

Comment: The $ cat test.tex is just the UNIX command line for printing the file to the screen.  My system is running Fedora 16 and is completely up-to-date.  I'll look into finding more up-to-date LaTeX packages.

Comment: @QuincyBowers I've removed the shell commands that, as you see, can be confusing for people not acquainted with the shell; who knows about the shell is sometimes surprised that other people have never heard about it. By the way, Qrrbrbirlbel was surely referring to the TeX distribution rather than the operating system. From the log file it can be seen that `scrartcl` is from 2006, while in the most recent TeX distributions it is dated 29 July 2012.

Comment: I just assumed that if Fedora said I was up to date than I should be reasonably up-to-date.  Apparently Fedora has an embarrassingly old version of LaTeX though.  I am updating it now.

Comment: @QuincyBowers I think all the Linux distros are quite behind the TeX releases. I use Fedora, but I always update TeX using the TeXLive DVD rather than use the "Add/Update Software" tool.

Comment: Assuming an update fixes the issue, please ping one of us back using the `@` syntax (for example, @cmhughes); we'll probably close it as too localized. Welcome to the group :)

Comment: It'll be another hour or so before the packages are finished updating.  I'll be sure to let you know how it goes.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: @cmhughes, updating to the latest TexLive did the trick.  Thanks again for the help everybody.  If someone want to post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: voted to close- thanks for letting us know- I'll flag for the moderator too